# How do I prevent a variable from continuously adding in a loop in python?

Tags: python

```
prob=1
classsize=1
for i in range(classsize):
    prob=prob*(365-i)/365
    if prob<0.1:
       print(classsize)
    elif prob>0.1:
       classsize+1
```

What I want this code to do is add one unit on to `classsize` and check if `prob<0.1`. If the statement is false I want the code to continue this cycle until `prob<0.1` and print the value of `classsize`.

Comment: Don't change `for` loop during executing it.

Comment: you don't want classsize to increment?

Comment: A while loop is perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `while` loop since you don't know how many times you need to go round.

(your for loop goes round a fixed number of times)

```
prob = 1
classsize = 1
while prob > 0.1:
    prob = prob * (365 - classsize) / 365
    classsize += 1

print(classsize)
```

output:

```
41
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks;)

Answer (score -1):

Try creating inner while loop. This code should do what you need

```
for i in range(classsize):
 while prob=prob*(365-i)/365 > 0.1:
  classsize+1
 print(classsize)
```

Comment: could you check that code ? It is probably not doing what you think it is doing.